# Combine Sheets from different workbooks with the same names into a master workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, consolidation

so I have about 21 sheets that are all named the exact same across about 16 files. All the formats and such are the exact same, so for example I need to combine all the sheets with "Age" in all 16 files into a master file that will have the "Age" sheet with the aggregated data of all 16 "Age" sheets. Similarly for the other 20 sheet types.

I'm not sure how exactly to do this. I have a macro that currently adds all sheets in a file together into one master workbook, and I'm looking to modify this so it combines similar sheets instead of just adding them all into one workbook.
Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
Sub AddAllWS()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\path\to"
Set wbDst = ThisWorkbook
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until strFilename = ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

        wsSrc.UsedRange.Copy

        wsSrc.Paste (wbSrc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1))


        wbSrc.Close False

    strFilename = Dir()

Loop
wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: At a quick glance, notice how you prefaced `Range` with the worksheet? You *must* do the same with `Rows.Count`, `Columns.Count`, `Cells()`, etc. Otherwise, VBA can get confused really quickly.  Try just doing that to see if it fixes your issue. (at the very least, it'll help tighten your code up!)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be copying and pasting into the same source worksheet. Check the code below. That might work. I put in comments in the code.

```
Sub AddAllWS()
    Dim wbDst As Workbook
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbDst = ThisWorkbook

    MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\path\to\"
    strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

    Do While strFilename <> ""

            Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & strFilename)

            'loop through each worksheet in the source file
            For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Worksheets
                'Find the corresponding worksheet in the destination with the same name as the source
                On Error Resume Next
                Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If wsDst.Name = wsSrc.Name Then
                    lLastRow = wsDst.UsedRange.Rows(wsDst.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
                    wsSrc.UsedRange.Copy
                    wsDst.Range("A" & lLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            Next wsSrc

            wbSrc.Close False
            strFilename = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```